# tortoisesvn dump/load from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My question is about...
i have installed tortoisesvn 1.7.6 version 32bit in a 32 bit windows machine, so in this machine i have a repository (many vb.net projects). I want to migrate all of this repository structure to a 64 bit windows machine and in this 64 bit machine i installed tortoisesvn 1.7.6 64 bits

I need to migrate all repositories so firstly dumped a small project and copied it to the 64 bit machine in a folder, then made a  svnadmin load command of this dumped file but it doesn't work, i specified the complete path of the dumped file.

It gave the error
svnadmin: E205000: too many arguments

I supuses that the format of 32bit dumped file couldn't be read in tortoisesvn 64 bit version.

Please could someone explain me what is the problem here?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Try using a path (and name) without white space " " for the dump file.  It probably just misinterprets these.

Comment: i t gave me e205000: too many arguments
the command line used is 
c:\svnrepo\svnadmin load c:\svnrepo\svnCopefa < c:\dumps\copefadmp.dump
so i don't have white spaces in the command line